# $_GET is will not return users or auth

Tags: php, arrays, .htaccess

I am working a website where users need to login. I am building a Restful API and have created a folder containing three files. I have an `index.php`, `.htaccess`, `DB.php`. My problem is that when I want to add a `print_r($_GET);` in the `index.php` file and then I go to the localhost page on the browser, I am getting this as a return  `Array ( [url] => index.php )` I instead want it to display `Array ( [url] => users )` or `Array ( [url] => auth )`. I am trying to get this to display users so I can pull the username and passwords when I test this on Postman. If I have been unclear on something, I will gladly fix my error in providing the information.

My index.php:

```
    <?php
    require_once("DB.php");

    $db = new DB("127.0.0.1", "users", "root", "");
    print_r($_GET);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
    if ($_GET['url'] == "auth") {

    } else if ($_GET['url'] == "users") {

  }
} else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
if ($_GET['url'] == "auth") {
    $postBody = file_get_contents("php://input");
}

} else {
 http_response_code(405);
}
?>
```

My .htaccess code:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: So what URL are you accessing?

Comment: index.php. I am going to my localhost page via Xampp and refreshing the browser from there.

Comment: I have tried localhost/restfulapi/index.php/users and still i get index.php

Comment: Your rewrite rule is invalid then.  Test here: http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Comment: Seems to me you should try accessing `localhost/restfulapi/users` or `localhost/restfulapi/auth`. That's what your rewrite rule appears to be configured for. I would also add the flags `[L,QSA]` to your rule

Comment: If I remove the index.php would it not simply return a not found error? I believe my problem is coming from the htaccess. I added back the tags, [L, QSA].

Comment: I tested the htaccess file and it says the conditions were not met for the line:  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?url=$1[L,QSA]

Comment: I also tried this: RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?url=$1&username=$2 [L], but it still did not work. I received an error in the browser for undefined url on lines 7 and 9 of index page